# Override "remaining elements truncated" in Python

Tags: python, django

I'm using the Python shell in Django to make some queries. The results keep getting truncated. I get the message, "remaining elements truncated." How can I see all the results? Or, how can I write the results to a file?

Comment: could you give the example query and what you would expect it to return?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Querysets do this automatically when you just output them in the shell  - which implictly calls `repr` on them. If you call `list` on the queryset instead, that will output everything:

```
list(MyModel.objects.all())
```

Note that you don't need to do this within your code, this is just for output within the shell. Obviously, beware of doing this on a model with a very large number of entries.

Answer (score 3):

The top answer returns an error for me in 2020:

```
Error in argument: '(MyModel.objects.all())'
```

What works for me is just iterating over the Queryset as a list comprehension:

```
[i for i in MyModel.objects.all()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Say your query is:

`>>> Foo.objects.all()`

Instead try:

`>>> for x in Foo.objects.all(): print x`

Or to dump them to a file:

```
>>> f = open('your_filename','w')
>>> for x in Foo.objects.all(): f.write(u'%s\n' % x)
>>> f.close()
```